# Dynamic div working but not showing the data

Tags: javascript, sqlite, dom

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong here? On the console log right after htmlStr=theName line I am getting the name as it was entered in the form, saved in the database, and queried back. However, I am getting no result showing in the page at the end. I have tested the div append and it is working. 
HTML

```
     <input id="allUsers" type="button" value="All users" onClick="queryDB();">
```

Javascript

```
     function queryDB() {
    var sqlStr = "SELECT * FROM USERS ORDER BY id ASC";
    console.log("SQL: " + sqlStr);
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
      tx.executeSql(sqlStr, [], querySuccess, onQueryFailure);
    }, onSqlError, onSqlSuccess);
    console.log("Leaving queryDB");
  }

      function querySuccess(tx, results) {
  console.log('You are in querysuccess');
  console.log(results);
  if (results.rows.length == 0) {
    $("#showUsers").html("No data");
    return false;
  }
  var htmlStr="";
  var theID;
  var theName;
  var thePhoto;
  var len = results.rows.length;
  console.log(len);
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        theID = results.rows.item(i).id;
        console.log(theID);
        theName = results.rows.item(i).username;
            htmlStr += theName;
        console.log(theName);
        thePhoto = results.rows.item(i).imagepath;
        console.log(thePhoto);
        var userDiv = document.createElement("div");//Create the div
        userDiv.innerHTML=htmlStr;
        document.getElementById('showUsers').appendChild(userDiv);//append it to the document
        userDiv.style.display = 'block';            
    };
}
```

Comment: How is querySuccess called?

Comment: It's called from a queryDB function - SELECT * FROM USERS etc.

Comment: You call a JavaScript function with a SQL statement? What starts off the process? Show the calling code. Is it a buton click, form submission, etc?

Comment: Apologies, in this instance that is called by the queryDB function which is firstly called with a button "All users". I have amended code to show both.

Comment: Do you forget to replate the `onSqlSuccess` with the right name of the handler `querySuccess`? After doing the query, did `div` elements created properly?

Comment: @Trung, yes the div append is working. The onSqlSuccess relates to the database connection method, not the actual transaction.

Comment: missing tag in my html form. Thanks.